# Prices: "As low as" vs. "starting from"

Tags: business-language

Today I received an email with the following advertisement:

> The SSL certicate can be renewed for as little as one year and for a price **as low as $7.9500.** RENEW TODAY!

I understood it the way that this means the price is $ 7.95 for one year. But later it came out that the prices are **starting from $ 7.95**, which is the price for a 5-year subscription. The 1-year subscription price actually is $ 9.00.

The support person told me

> As you have probably noticed there is a phrase "As low as" which means that the price depends on the amount of years for which the certificate is ordered.

If it is correct to interpret the "as low as" from the offer's text this way, is there a difference between the original offer quoted above and something like that:

> The SSL certicate can be renewed for as little as one year and for prices **starting from $7.9500.** RENEW TODAY!

Does it mean the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they mean exactly the same here.

There's a difference in the phrases in that "as low as" can be used with a conditional *could*, in that if I say "the price could be as low as $10", then I believe it wouldn't be any lower, but I'm leaving it open that it could well be higher.

But since they are actually setting the price here, rather than deducing or guessing them, then "as low as" essentially means the same thing as "starting from".